# JSON array and JSF

Tags: json, jsf

I'm working with JSF and EXT js.
I have a JSONArray created in the server-side and I want to pass it to client-side.
I used  to get the array and put it in javascript var. But this tag adds a html tag (span) which make an error in javascript var.

This is the code I wrote:

```
var data1 = <h:outputFormat value="#{actorBean.newactors}" />
```

And this is the code of my page after running:

```
var data1 =<span>[[&quot;aaaaaaa&quot;,&quot;bbbbbbb&quot;]]</span>
```

so do u have any idea how to get the array without all the tags added ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<h:outputText value="#{actorBean.newactors}" escape="false">
```

The `h:outputFormat` is only interesting if you want to [format your messages](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html). The `escape` attribute of the `h:outputText` will disable escaping of HTML entities like `"` into `&quot;`.

Comment: I want to escape the whole html tag :)
my data should be this like this :
var data1= [["aaa","bbb"]]
so the problem persists with the "span" tag
how can I strip this tag ?

Comment: Then leave the `escape` attribute away. Only ensure that you don't give it any `id` or `styleClass` or consorts, it would indeed otherwise render a `<span>` (*with* the `id`, `class`, etc).

Comment: I put it without these params and still get the span tag :(
No id... no Style class
Im desperate

Comment: Note: <h:outputText escape="false">#{actorBean.newactors}</h:outputText> doesn't work (in JSF1)

Comment: @Topera: I've also never mentioned that. The value has to go in `value` attribute instead. EL in template text is indeed only supported in Facelets 2.x.

Comment: @BalusC: ok, I'm just sharing why I lose 30 minutes :). Tks!